# Recurring events on event_calendar

Tags: ruby-on-rails, calendar, recurring-events, ice-cube

I am trying to implement recurring events for [event_calendar](https://github.com/elevation/event_calendar) and it is turing out to be quite challenge. It seem I have to write the recurrence for my events from scratch. I have no problem with that as long as I am not missing a better way of doing it that has already been implemented and that I could potentially even contribute to.

How did or do you recommend implementing recurring events for a calendar such as event_calendar?

If I have to start from scratch what advices could you give?
Would you use [Ice_cube](https://github.com/seejohnrun/ice_cube)? Can you describe your approach? Thank you so much.

Comment: Hi! How did you ended up solving this question?

Comment: Turn our my clients did not need recurring events so I actually did not implemente it. If you implement it I would like to know how you decided to go about it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Second question with more details and also a little more specific but with and answer.

[Find it here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9123711/event-calendar-time-zone)